# Invalid types float[int] for array subscript in a for loop

Tags: c++

I'm not familiar with c++. I've been doing a  question. I need to pass the values from the first two functions(weight & height) to calcbmi function. There's an error in for loop in calcbmi function. Also it says "cannot convert 'float*' to 'float'" in main method calcbmi.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void inputweight(float weight[], int size) {
    cout << "Enter weights in kilogram: ";
    int i = 0, w;

    while (i < size) {
        cin >> w;

        if (w >= 45 && w <= 200) {
            weight[i] = w;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            cout << "The value should be between 45-200." << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Weights: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << weight[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void inputheight(float height[], int size) {
    float h;
    cout << "Enter height in cm: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ) {
        cin >> h;

        if (h >= 140 && h <= 200) {
            height[i] = h;
            i++;
        }
    }
     
    cout << "Heights: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       cout << height[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void calcbmi (float weight, float height, float bmi, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        bmi[i] = weight[i] / (height[i] / 100 * height[i] / 100);
    }

    cout << "BMI values:";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << bmi[i] << " " << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int size;
    cout << "Enter numebr of students: ";
    cin >> size;
    float weight[size], height[size], bmi[size];

    inputweight(weight, size);
    inputheight(height, size);
    calcbmi(weight, height, bmi, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Unrelated*: `float weight[size],height[size],bmi[size];` - [VLAs are not Standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard), consider using [`std::vector<float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Requests for debugging help should focus on *one* error only and include a [mre]. You should remove the code that is not required to reproduce your chosen error. This usually means removing the functionality that you want in your program, but this is OK -- you are removing it from the *example* code in your question, not from your program. For an error while compiling, the example code usually can be well under a dozen lines.

Comment: questions about a compiler error should include the compiler error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `void calcbmi (float weight,float height, float bmi, int size)` and you'll see that `bmi` is *a* `float` - not a `float[]`, so you can't do `bmi[i] = ...`. The same goes for `weight` and `height`.

The proper signature of the function should be:

```
void calcbmi (float weight[],float height[], float bmi[], int size)
```

Your program is however not strictly conforming C++ since you are using *variable length arrays*:

```
float weight[size],height[size],bmi[size];
```

I suggest replacing those with:

```
std::vector<float> weight(size), height(size), bmi(size);
```

It could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

// One function that can be used for both weights and heights:
bool inputvector(std::vector<float>& values, std::string_view heading,
                 std::string_view unit, float min, float max)
{
    std::cout << "Enter " << heading << "s in " << unit << '\n';

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < values.size();) {
        std::cout << heading << ' ' << (i + 1) << ": ";

        // check that input succeeds and deal with failure
        if(not(std::cin >> values[i])) {
            // something went bad
            if(std::cin.eof()) return false; // no way to recover

            // some bad input, clear the failbit and empty the input buffer:
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "Invalid input, try again.\n";
        } else if(values[i] >= min && values[i] <= max) {
            ++i;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Only " << heading << "s between " << min << " and "
                      << max << ' ' << unit << " are allowed, try again.\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << heading << "s:";
    for(auto value : values) std::cout << ' ' << value;
    std::cout << '\n';
    return true;
}

void calcbmi(std::vector<float>& weight, std::vector<float>& height,
             std::vector<float>& bmi)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < bmi.size(); i++) {
        bmi[i] = weight[i] / (height[i] / 100 * height[i] / 100);
    }

    std::cout << "BMI values:";
    for(auto value : bmi) std::cout << ' ' << value;
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int size;

    std::cout << "Enter number of students: ";

    // check that input succeeds and that it's greater than zero:
    if(std::cin >> size && size > 0) {
        std::vector<float> weight(size), height(size), bmi(size);

        if(inputvector(weight, "weight", "kg", 45, 200) &&
           inputvector(height, "height", "cm", 140, 200))
        {
            calcbmi(weight, height, bmi);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are not going to use `bmi` after `calcbmi`, you don't really need to declare it outside the `calcbmi` function. You could just calculate the BMI values and print them directly in the `calcbmi` function.

Answer (score 1):

Your calcbmi function should take arrays, not floats:

```cpp
void calcbmi(float weight[], float height[], float bmi[], int size)
```

Your program will work after making that change.
However, there are other issues, for example, you are creating arrays of variable size, which is not allowed in strict c++.
You might want to consider using std::vector, which will make much of this easier